# Rotated Paraboloid Surface Fitting

Tags: python, matlab, curve-fitting, least-squares, surface

I have a set of experimentally determined (x, y, z) points which correspond to a parabola. Unfortunately, the data is not aligned along any particular axis, and hence corresponds to a rotated parabola.

I have the following general surface:
Ax^2 + By^2 + Cz^2 + Dxy + Gyz + Hzx + Ix + Jy + Kz + L = 0

I need to produce a model that can represent the parabola accurately using (I'm assuming) least squares fitting. I cannot seem to figure out how this works. I have though of rotating the parabola until its central axis lines up with z-axis but I do not know what this axis is. Matlab's cftool only seems to fit equations of the form z = f(x, y) and I am not aware of anything in python that can solve this.
I also tried solving for the parameters numerically. When I tried making this into a matrix equation and solving by least squares, the matrix turned out to be invertible and hence my parameters were just all zero. I also am stuck on this and any help would be appreciated. I don't really mind the method as I am familiar with matlab, python and linear algebra if need be.

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen this http://nl.mathworks.com/help/optim/examples/nonlinear-data-fitting.html

Comment: In python I use curve_fit from scipy. It is accept vector values of x, so I represent 3D data as a 1D table.

Answer (score 2):

Dont use any toolboxes, GUIs or special functions for this problem. Your problem is very common and the equation you provided may be solved in a very straight-forward manner. The solution to the linear least squares problem can be outlined as:

1. The basis of the vector space is x^2, y^2, z^2, xy, yz, zx, x, y, z, 1. Therefore your vector has 10 dimensions.
2. Your problem may be expressed as Ap=b, where p = [A B C D E F G H I J K L]^T is the vector containing your parameters. The right hand side b should be all zeros, but will contain some residual due to model errors, uncertainty in the data or for numerical reasons. This residual has to be minimized.
3. The matrix A has a dimension of N by 10, where N denotes the number of known points on surface of the parabola.

A = [x(1)^2 y(1)^2 ... y(1) z(1) 1

...

x(N)^2 y(N)^2 ... y(N) z(N) 1]

4. Solve the overdetermined system of linear equations by computing p = A\b.

Comment: Hi Diphthong, I did construct this matrix and it had size 120 X 10 matrix. I also had b as a 120 X 1 vector. When I tried solving the equation I simply got that the matrix was invertible and hence the coefficient vector was all zero.
I understand that the problem is most likely due to your step 2. I don't know what you mean by 'the right hand side b...will contain some residual due to model errors,...'. In other words, how can I get a nonzero b?

Comment: It turns out your coefficents are linearly depent. Of course the trivial solution is that all are zero. You need to get rid of one parameter. I suggest you define that L = -1. Then you can put the last column of the matrix A on the right hand side. Your new matrix A* should have dimensions of N x 9 and the new b* should be all ones. I will edit my post accordingly if you succeed using this modification, so please let me know if you do so.

Comment: I defined the constant parameter as you said (L = -1). This then gave me a vector of ones. My new matrix was N x 9 as you said. When I solved the equation I got that all of the parameters were zero except for the x, y and z components and of course the constant parameter (defined L = 1). This of course corresponds to a planewhen I actually need a paraboloid.
I was wondering if you had any suggestions for this?

Comment: Try to computing the residual r = A*p - b. If it is zero or very small, your parabolic equation holds, at least for the selected points. In this case you need to analyse how this can happen. If the residual is non-zero, the least squares problem has not been solved correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enough data points to fit all 10 parameters - you will need at least 10?

I also suspect that 10 parameters are to many to describe a general paraboloid, meaning that some of the parameters are dependent. My fealing is that a translated and rotated paraboloid needs 7 parameters (although I'm not really sure)

Comment: I have well over a hundred points so I'm sure it should be okay. I'm also sure that the 10 parameter equation corresponds to the full general surface for a quadric surface. If some of these are indeed unnecessary I would think some would become zeros - I have enough points to ensure this.

Comment: A full general quadric surface can be other surfaces than a paraboloid. Constraints on the surface makes it a paraboloid, reducing the number of parameters (to 7?). In your equation one parameter can immediately be eliminated by division, so it is at most 9 independent parameters even for a general quadratic. Furthermore, general quadratic surfaces can lay in complex (numbers) space, further complicating the fitting. 

To aid the fitting, rewrite the equation and eliminate some parameters to correspond to a paraboloid.